# Type Family Polymorphism

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, type-families

So I have a function `apply :: proxy tf -> tf Int -> tf Int` which takes a Proxy intended to carry a type family and applies Int to that type family to determine the type of the second argument and return value.
However, I'm getting some confusing responses from GHC.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Proxy

type family F (a :: *) :: * where
    F Int = ()

f :: Proxy F
f = Proxy

apply :: proxy tf -> tf Int -> tf Int
apply _ x = x

-- Doesn't typecheck.
test1 :: ()
test1 = apply f ()

-- Typechecks fine
test2 :: ()
test2 = let g = apply f in g ()
```

`test1` refuses to compile with GHC spitting out this error:

```
tftest.hs:16:9:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘()’ with actual type ‘F Int’
    In the expression: apply f ()
    In an equation for ‘test1’: test1 = apply f ()

tftest.hs:16:17:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘F Int’ with actual type ‘()’
    In the second argument of ‘apply’, namely ‘()’
    In the expression: apply f ()
```

Confusingly, commenting out `test1` and using a let binding in `test2` makes GHC happy and everything compiles fine. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> So I have a function `apply :: proxy tf -> tf Int -> tf Int` which takes a Proxy intended to carry a type family

You can't do this. Type families must always be fully applied, like the type synonyms of which they are a generalization. A type variable can never be instantiated to a under-saturated type family.

It's a bug in GHC 7.8.3 that it did not already reject your program starting at

```
f :: Proxy F
```